# Subclassing a UIViewController implementing UITableView delegate and datasource: code reuse

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios, uikit, uiviewcontroller

I have some initialisation code in the `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear:` methods that is used across a number of my UIViewController subclasses (which implement < UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>):

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero
        style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.tableView.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```

My thinking is to subclass UIViewController and include these methods in the subclass so as not to have to write this code in all my view controllers.

What are your thoughts on this? I'm wondering if this might give rise to issues retaining the tableView.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered this structure:

UIViewController -> your_First_Level_Subclass_View_Controller -> your_Second_Level_Subclass_View_Controller

In the 1st level, you implement those reusable/tableView-related codes, but you don't actually use this 1st level controller. You then subclass this 1st level to create your 2nd level controllers, which are the ultimate controller that you are gonna use.

Comment: Yes that is my thinking. I am just conscious that the application will grow to the size where classes would inherit different functionality from different parent view controllers and I don't want a) 3, 4, 5, ..., N levels b) to start duplicating functionality across my First Level view controllers. So I think another way would be better.